# Validate phone number in joomla 2.5

Tags: validation, joomla

I can validate email id by adding validate-email class to the input filed.

How can I validate an input field of phone number? also, how can we validate a numeric, integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try.

> validate-numeric

[read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation)

For phone numbers you may try

> validate-[custom]

Comment: its giving error : Validation Rule missing: numeric