# How can we show error message on form validation on joomla 2.5 in the same way as email validation with a tooltip like alert?

Tags: validation, joomla

How can we show error message on form validation on joomla 2.5 in the same way as email validation etc? with the tool tip?

I have included

```
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
```

and I have a script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      var msg = new Array();
                document.formvalidator.setHandler('phone', function (value) {  return (value != '123'); }     );
        });
```

and My input filed is like

```
<input name="jform[contact_phone]" type="text" id="jform_contact_phone"  class='validate-phone'/>
```

I am getting the tooltip for email field validation and required filed validation, but I can not include numeric validation and I could not implement a tooltip message for my custom phone number field.

I am using joomla 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check here for custom validation

http://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation

You have to add like below:

```
 window.addEvent('domready', function(){
   document.formvalidator.setHandler('birth', function(value) {
      regex=/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/;
      return regex.test(value);
   });
});
```

If its only for numeric click below URL and try this also:

[Validate phone number in joomla 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947785/validate-phone-number-in-joomla-2-5)