# validation giving error in Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 user registration form . manually i added one more field user phone number . and i am doing server side validation .

Code is : registration.xml

```
          <form
          addrulepath="/administrator/components/com_user/models/rules"
          >
         <field 
         name="pnumber" 
         type="text"
        description="Enter your valid Number"
        label="Phone number:"
        required="true"
        size="30"
        hint="EX:080-12345678"
        validate="mobile"

        />
```

and i have created validation file in administrator\components\com_users\models\rules\mobile.php

code is :

```
     <?php


  defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

    jimport('joomla.form.formrule');


   class JFormRuleMobile extends JFormRule
       {


public function mobile(& $element, $value, $group = null, & $input = null, & $form = null)
     {
    return preg_match("/^\+{0,1}[0-9]{6,14}$/",$value);
        }
    }

   ?>
```

when i submit the form  "Validation Rule missing: mobile" error is coming.
what is the problem . where i am doing mistakes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate phone number in joomla 2.5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947785/validate-phone-number-in-joomla-2-5)

Comment: No ,,that question Not helped at all.

Comment: when and where did you called that function to validate?

Comment: do not add/edit core files its not recommended, You can create Plugins Joomla already comes with sample profile plugin check the code and catch the proper [plugin](https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) events !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its very simple ...

just use joomla inbuilt rule called "tel" .its very good for validate the phone number

more info [joomla document about this](https://docs.joomla.org/Server-side_form_validation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the behaviour of validate on your form.
Add form-validate class to your form as well.
you have different classes:-

1. required
2. validate-username
3. validate-password
4. validate-numeric
5. validate-email
6. validate-[custom] -> custom defined 
   [Use this link for Joomla](https://docs.joomla.org/Client-side_form_validation)

Or you can easily validate the form using **jQuery** or HTML's **required** attribte and **pattern** attribute.

Comment: please check i have modified my question . i am using server side validation